# Share phone's internet over existinf wifi network

Tags: networking, internet, mobile-network

i want to share my phone's 3g over my existing wifi network. NOT hotspot ( because phone's wifi signal is too weak). is this possible?

Comment: Where is the source of this "existing Wi-Fi"?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat An adsl modem/router

Comment: I don't it is possible to do thatcfrom that setup in my opinion